# Discovering a valid aggregation from two collections, one of which is an aggregation of the other

Tags: algorithm, scala, aggregation

Suppose I have two types:

```
case class X(i: Int) 
case class Y(j: Int)
```

And the `X`s represent some aggregation of `Y`s (but I have lost the information as to exactly which `Y`s composed a given `X`). I wish to calculate some valid aggregation:

```
def aggregate(xs: List[X], ys: List[Y]): Map[X, List[Y]] = {
  require(xs.nonEmpty)
  require(ys.nonEmpty)
  require(xs.count <= ys.count)
  require(xs.map(_.i).sum == ys.map(_.j).sum)

 lazy val result: List[X, List[Y]] = sys.error("todo: implement me!")

 assert(result forall { case (x, ys) => x.i == ys.map(_.j).sum })
 //assume an assertion that each input x and y appears exactly once in the result
 result
```

}

Obviously in general this is not possible; for example, there could be no valid result here:

```
aggregate(List(X(1), X(3)), List(Y(2), Y(2))
```

But for my use-case, I know that my method cannot be called with non-aggregatable values.

---

**EDIT**: *I'm going to add an explanation of what actually is going on. Basically I have two sources of trades, one of which may be aggregated arbitrarily. That is, from one source, I might see 2 trades both having a quantity of 1, whereas from the other source I might see only one trade with a quantity of 2. I am trying to knit together the sources of trades, so that the resulting `Map` says "this aggregate trade of 2 was actually composed of two trades of 1"*

Comment: what is `List[X,List[Y]]` ? List only takes one type parameter. The rest of your question is incomprehensible to me, too.

Comment: I meant `Map[X, List[Y]]` - the question is supposed to distil the problem down to types

Comment: Isn't this the knapsack problem stated a different way?

Comment: It might be, Rex; unfortunately I did maths at university so have never heard of it

Comment: You are certainly right in that I would probably be better off using ilp to solve this